# Using CodeIgniter how do I save user info from checkbox in a cookie?

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is a page that I am working on that has a sort of ToDo checklist on it, that I need to create a cookie for so that when a user comes back to the page everything they have previously checked off will show. I have seen so many different ways of accomplishing it, but I am having difficulty translating the bits I have seen over to my CodeIgniter built page. What is the best way of getting this to work? Here is what I am working with so far.

> Inside of the view file

```
<section class="chkBoxes">
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo form_checkbox('toDoBox', 'reviewed', FALSE); ?> Test</li>
        <li><?php echo form_checkbox('toDoBox', 'reviewed', FALSE); ?> Test</li>
        <li><?php echo form_checkbox('toDoBox', 'reviewed', FALSE); ?> Test</li>
        <li><?php echo form_checkbox('toDoBox', 'reviewed', FALSE); ?> Test</li>
        <li><?php echo form_checkbox('toDoBox', 'reviewed', FALSE); ?> Test</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Had this working in my test.php page but get errors when I moved this into CI

> Inside of the controller

```
$this->session->set_userdata('');

    $aDoor = $_POST['toDoBox'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("Please mark what you have read before continuing.");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);

    echo("You have completed $N sections: ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");
    }
  }
```

Comment: A couple of points - each `form_checkbox()`'s first argument must be unique (this translates to the `name` element; you shouldn't be trying to set your userdata inside the view, this is the controllers job.

Comment: Should have marked them properly in here, all of that code is not in the view.

Comment: OK - in a nutshell: give each checkbox a unique name and cycle through them in the controller when form is submitted setting a unique userdata item for each one, then in your view pull that userdata out and display checked checkboxes accordingly.  See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html for further details on use of session class.